# A diminishing plastic protector

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> When being exhaustive, I'm found on a horse.
>   Attacked by the mob I'm essential, of course.
>   When being artistic I'm holding up well.
>   In a refuge I couldn't escape from Hell.
>   When wearing a crown I'll be found in the centre.
>   With a british policeman - dishevelled preventer.
>   When I come from the earth I prefer wetter weather.
>   Teddy needs me divided to keep him together.

**Question**: What am I?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Pin

When being exhaustive, I'm found on a horse.

> Thoroughpin is a swelling of the tendon sheath above the hock of a horse.

Attacked by the mob I'm essential, of course.

> An attack by the mob could be a lynch, and a lynchpin is an essential person or thing to an operation.

When being artistic I'm holding up well.

> A drawing pin is used to hold things up

In a refuge I couldn't escape from Hell.

> Hell refers to Richard Hell a pioneer of punk fashion noted for using "safety pins". Safety refers to the refuge

When wearing a crown I'll be found in the centre.

> A kingpin is found at the centre of a set of bowling pins (and perhaps a secret crime organisation)

With a british policeman - dishevelled preventer.

> "Bobby pin" - as pointed out by Deusovi

When I come from the earth I prefer wetter weather.

> A terrapin is a species of turtle which lives in fresh or brackish water and "terra" is Latin for Earth.

Teddy needs me divided to keep him together.

> Split pin - a device used largely in the manufacture of teddies

A diminishing plastic protector

> A PIN code is a password used as an extra layer of security at an ATM on top of a plastic debit/credit card so could be seen as a plastic protector. Diminishing refers to the fact that a usual type of pin diminishes to a point.

Comment: The policeman one is "bobby pin". Nice solution!

Comment: Thank you @Deusovi I also added the line which I missed beforehand.

Comment: All right except for the 'earth' and the plastic protector. I had considered including a clue surrounding electrical plugs, but didn't include it.

Comment: @GordonK Is the 'earth' clue a 'spring-pin' used in umbrellas. My reference is  patent I found for an umbrella : http://www.google.com/patents/US377455

Comment: No - a lot less obscure than that and alive. For the title think uppercase!

Comment: Thank you for the hints. I've updated my guess accordingly.

Comment: 'Diminishing' was actually intended to reflect the growing use of contactless payment, but everything else is exactly right.